# Busting Craft Cache

Tags: templating, cache

I've been looking around and can't seem to find anything, maybe it's not possible.

For a forum plugin I'm toying with, topics use more data outside of the page in craft's db, so I need a way to bust the cache as craft won't be able to detect a change. So is there a way to 'bust' the Craft Cache possibly with a variable? I'd love to be able to do something like:

```
{% set param = craft.request.getParam( 'newreply' ) %}

{% cache globally using key craft.request.path until param == '1' %}
    {# generated page content #}
{% endcache %}
```

This way it'd stay cached until the page was requested with `?newreply=1`, effectively busting the cache.

This doesn't seem to be working though. Does anyone have any ideas how this could be accomplished? If not possible with twig, would there be a way to do it in a plugin?

For example, what if I did something like:

```
{# twig template #}

{{ craft.myplugin.clearcache( craft.request.path ) }}



{# MyPluginVariable.php #}

public function clearcache($pageid)
{

    craft()->templateCache->deleteCacheById($pageid);

    return true;

}
```

That doesn't seem to do anything though

Comment: I wonder what happens if you set the `until` value to a time in the past?  Something like `now|date_modify("-1 day")`

Comment: Tried it out, doesn't bust cache :[

Comment: What if you append the query string to the key? I.e. ```{% cache globally using key craft.request.path ~ '?' ~ craft.request.queryString %}```

Comment: That wouldn't get the effect I'm hoping for, as I'd like to flush the cache for the page without the query string. Basically what I want to accomplish is whenever someone writes a new reply to a forum topic, their browser would refresh the page with ?newreply=1, flushing the topic's cache so everyone can see the new response

Comment: Can you make the forum plugin expose the timestamp of the newest reply to Twig? If so, you could change the cache tag to something like: {% cache globally using key 'page-content-' ~ craft.myForumPlugin.newestReplyTimestamp %}. Would create one extra db query, but it'd be as simple as they get.

Comment: FWIW, you're original example won't work because [until](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/cache#until) is specifically looking for a date/time.

Comment: @AndréElvan Very interesting idea. That would certainly work, would Craft store the old cache for the previous keys though?

Comment: @ZackTaylor Where are your "replies" stored? Outside of Craft? Where does the POST request for the reply form go?

Comment: @ZackTaylor Craft would store the cache until it expires (as specified with the for keyword), but would automatically delete it later.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDIT**

[Craft 2.4](http://buildwithcraft.com/updates#build2664) is now available, adding the [deleteCachesByKey](https://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/TemplateCacheService#deleteCachesByKey-detail) method. This means the following would be the best solution to this question:

```
public function clearcache($key)
{
    craft()->templateCache->deleteCachesByKey($key);
}
```

---

**ORIGINAL**

Your original attempt using a variable method will actually work (as long as the call to the variable method `clearcache` occurs before the cache tag in your template, of course).

*Your problem is that the* `deleteCacheById()` *method expects the template cache's database ID, not the cache key.*

Unfortunately, [TemplateCacheService](https://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/TemplateCacheService) doesn't actually offer an easy way to delete a cache by its key, so you'll need to get your hands dirty with a custom SQL query:

```
public function clearcache( $key )
{
    craft()->db->createCommand()->delete( 'templatecaches', 'cacheKey=:key', array( ':key'=> $key ) );
}
```

**Disclaimer**: I'd imagine there's a good reason *why* there's no core `deleteCacheByKey` method, so it'd be great if somebody with a deeper knowledge of template caches could chime in. Might be there's some ramifications or negative side effects to deleting a cache manually like this.

Sidenote 1: Since the `clearcache` method shouldn't return any data, consider using Twig's [do](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/do.html) method to call it:

```
{% do craft.myplugin.clearcache( craft.request.path ) %}
```

Sidenote 2: Instead of using a combination of GET variables and plugin variable methods to clear the cache, you might want to consider an implementation where you POST your "replies" form to a *controller action method* in your plugin. The controller could then be responsible for

1. Saving the reply (possibly to an external application using cURL?)
2. Busting the relevant template cache w/ a custom DbCommand
3. Redirecting back to the referring page

Having a controller (which in turn might call methods on a *service* to execute on the above points) might, in my opinion, make for a cleaner implementation than the proposed solution (just based on the limited information you've provided, of course – I wouldn't know about the details or inner workings of your application).

Comment: Thanks, Mats! Your modification to 'clearcache()' worked exactly as is, nice! I moved it all out of twig and instead the clearcache() function is being triggered by the service that handles inserting new replies, I agree that is a much cleaner implementation. 

For now, I think this is good enough to move on from, but I am curious to learn more about the craft caching and why there isn't core functionality to do this. There probably is a good reason. If anyone also has any thoughts/knowledge on this I'd love to read about it for curiosities sake.

Comment: Nice fix Mats! I totally agree... `deleteCacheByKey` should probably be an official thing. Might be worth posting a feature request on [feedback.buildwithcraft.com](http://feedback.buildwithcraft.com/)!

Comment: I concur – and so does apparently Brandon Kelly, as he added a feature request for it a few weeks back :) -> http://feedback.buildwithcraft.com/forums/285221-feature-requests/suggestions/7179242-templatecacheservice-deletecachesbykey

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this but I'm pretty sure what you want is:

```
{% cache globally using key craft.request.path unless param == '1' %}
```

More information on the unless parameter can be found at http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/cache

Comment: I've tried this, it does bypass the cache if param == '1', but does not clear the cache, which is what I'm trying to do